# how to restrict ciphers, TLS1 and TLS1.1 while compiling OpenSSL with FIPS Module?

Tags: c, linux, ssl, openssl

i am trying to compile OpenSSL (1.0.2h) with FIPS module (2.0.12) from source in which i need to additionally restrict all ECDHE, DHE, DSA, DES and DH Ciphers as well as TLSV1 and TLSV1.1 Protocol. Here are the steps that i did:

```
> root@cc3:/home/openssl#wget https://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz

> root@cc3:/home/openssl#wget https://openssl.org/source/openssl-fips-2.0.12.tar.gz

> root@cc3:/home/openssl#tar -xvf openssl-fips-2.0.12.tar.gz

> root@cc3:/home/openssl#tar -xvf openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz

> root@cc3:/home/openssl#cd openssl-fips-2.0.12 && ./config -d && make && make install

> root@cc3:/home/openssl#cd /openssl-1.0.2h && ./config no-ssl2 no-ssl3
  no-tls1 no-ecdhe no-dsa no-des no-dh --prefix=/home/openssl/local fips
  && make depend && make && make install
```

After doing the above steps, openssl compiles successfully and i can access it from /home/openssl/local/bin. However, when checking the list of available ciphers, i can still see ECDHE, DHE, DHA etc. in the list and i can even use them and TLSV1 protocol to connect to any website using s_client. The point is that the flags for configuring OpenSSL are not working for me.

Can anyone help me in figuring out exactly what is it that i am missing here? Am i doing something wrong and if yes then what can be done to fix the problem so that the Cipher Suites and older TLS Protocols are restricted? I used the method provided [here](https://gist.github.com/steakknife/8247726) to get a list of all possible parameters for config.

Also, is there a way to selectively restrict AES and RSA Ciphers? For example is there a way to disable AES256-SHA but keep open AES128-SHA?

Thanks!

Comment: The FIPS object module and the cipher list are two different things. The FIPS object module provides AES, SHA, HMAC, etc. It does not contain SSL cipher suites. Cipher suites are part of the FIPS Capable OpenSSL library.

Comment: right. so if i want to restrict certain ciphers in addition to attaching the fips module to my openssl library then how can i do that?